# How to get the index of an element within an Array [Array [{JSON}]] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have something like this `(...)`,

```
json
[
 [{id:0, name:test, data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:1, name:test, data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:2, name:test, data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:3, name:test, data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:4, name:test, data:{},other:'...'}]
]
```

And I want to get the index of the element with `id=2`. For example, I have tried in many ways (with `find`, `findIndex` ) but it did not work. It's probably because I have the wrong search function, so I come to ask for help in this code

Comment: Add what you have tried and the error you got, in the question.

Comment: `findIndex` should work. Note that you have a 2D array. So, you need to take the `0` index before accesing `id` like: `arr.findIndex(o => o[0].id === 2)`

Comment: There's no [JSON](http://json.org) in your example (arrays)

Comment: updated my answer. let me know if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = [
 [{id:0, name:'test', data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:1, name:'test', data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:2, name:'test', data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:3, name:'test', data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:4, name:'test', data:{},other:'...'}]
]

console.log(input.findIndex(items => items.some(item => item.id === 2)));
```

Comment: updated my answer. let me know if that doesn't help

Answer (score -1):

```js
var test = "test";
var myArray = [
 [{id:0, name:test, data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:1, name:test, data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:2, name:test, data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:3, name:test, data:{},other:'...'}],
 [{id:4, name:test, data:{},other:'...'}]
];

myIndex = myArray.indexOf(myArray.filter(items => items.some(item => item.id === 2))[0]);
console.log('myIndex: '+ myIndex);
```